# android studio does not show layout preview new version (Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am new in android developement. I was facing a problem that layout preview was not showing in my XML files then I upgraded to new version of android and I thought that may the issue will solve but the problem is still here and I am very tense about it it is very difficult to design an app without design preview please if anyone of you can help me I will be motivated and thankful for you.

[image: SS of layout is:]

Comment: Without XML Layout files It is not Possible to help you , Post XML layout File

Comment: all xml  not show or only one?

Comment: only the default layout with the textView "hello world" is showing.

Comment: Vaibhav --> i have added a picture in question please check now. Code is available but only preview is not.

Comment: @MUHAMMADHASEEB please Post XML layout File Code Not Picture We can Check Error in Code not in Picture

Comment: @Vaibhav bro i have deleted that project and started again newly now it is showing but I am facing another problem about signup with firebase authentication using email and password I have posted a question please if you know then help me.

Comment: @Vaibhav here the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691573/how-to-signup-with-email-and-password-using-firebase-authentication-android-stud

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. We have solved it the way that we have downloaded the new Android SDK.