# how to Signup with email and password using firebase authentication android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to signup using firebase with email and password but when I am adding onclicklistner on signup button and try to signup and run app then Gradle build is successfully run but the app is crashing there is no error in the code here the code of signup activity:

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ActivitySignUpBinding binding;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseDatabase database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sign Up");
    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    binding.SignUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(binding.EmailTv.getText().toString() ,binding.PasswordTv.
                 getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                 if(task.isSuccessful()){
                     Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User created successfully",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                 else{
                     Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
         });
        }
    });



   binding.alreadyHaveAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Gradle build app level:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

android {
compileSdk 30

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdk 16
    targetSdk 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
   // Declare the dependency for the Firebase Authentication library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
```

}

Logcat code:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.myapplication. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:183)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
    at com.example.myapplication.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6915)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

.when I remove onclicklistner from the signup button the app launch.
please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: you have to check the error message in the ```logcat``` of Android Studio that causes the app crash

Comment: @JabalLogian please check now

Comment: @JabalLogian i think this    ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.myapplication. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.                                                                      
  at com.example.myapplication.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:32))              
 is error but i have initialized firebase get reference in on create method please check if I made any mistake.

Comment: You're not calling `initializeApp` anywhere in the code you shared, which explains why you get the error message. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977847/make-sure-to-call-firebaseapp-initializeappcontext-first-in-android and probably more of the results of searching for the error message: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Make+sure+to+call+FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)+first